# I'm unable to download Python Packages for Visual Studio Community 2022

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, pip, pypi

Every time I try installing a package through Python Environments, I get the same error. I've reinstalled both Python and Visual Studio several times but still cannot get the packages to install. currently what i get is the following:

```
----- Installing 'requests' -----
Collecting requests
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000238A9EF1780>, 'Connection to files.pythonhosted.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /packages/ca/91/6d9b8ccacd0412c08820f72cebaa4f0c0441b5cda699c90f618b6f8a1b42/requests-2.28.1-py3-none-any.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000238A9EF1A20>, 'Connection to files.pythonhosted.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /packages/ca/91/6d9b8ccacd0412c08820f72cebaa4f0c0441b5cda699c90f618b6f8a1b42/requests-2.28.1-py3-none-any.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000238A9EF1BA0>, 'Connection to files.pythonhosted.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /packages/ca/91/6d9b8ccacd0412c08820f72cebaa4f0c0441b5cda699c90f618b6f8a1b42/requests-2.28.1-py3-none-any.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000238A9EF1C90>, 'Connection to files.pythonhosted.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /packages/ca/91/6d9b8ccacd0412c08820f72cebaa4f0c0441b5cda699c90f618b6f8a1b42/requests-2.28.1-py3-none-any.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000238A9EF1E10>, 'Connection to files.pythonhosted.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /packages/ca/91/6d9b8ccacd0412c08820f72cebaa4f0c0441b5cda699c90f618b6f8a1b42/requests-2.28.1-py3-none-any.whl
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/ca/91/6d9b8ccacd0412c08820f72cebaa4f0c0441b5cda699c90f618b6f8a1b42/requests-2.28.1-py3-none-any.whl (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000238A9EF1F90>, 'Connection to files.pythonhosted.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)'))
[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.2.1 -> 22.2.2
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
----- Failed to install 'requests' -----
```

When I try to update pip, i get a Syntax Error, so I haven't even been able to do that.

I've spent most of my day trying to get this to work, but I've had no luck. Any help at all is greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you possibly behind a corporate proxy you haven't configured Pip to use?

Comment: That could be the case, but I used to use it no problem here at work, i only started having trouble with it today

Comment: Then ask your proxy maintainers for help.